# jquery Bootstrap two modals on same page conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two modals on the same page.

- The first one shows up upon opening the page. It's just a text modal.
- The second one shows upon clicking on a button. It's a modal with an input to enter an email.

**The problem I have is that I cannot type anything in the second modal.**

I have the following HTML :

```
<section class="border"> <a href="#">
                <button id="stop_button">Stop</button>
            </a> </section>


    <!-- 1st popup : INFO -->

    <div class="modal custom fade" id="trackModal" tabindex="-1"
        role="dialog" aria-labelledby="trackModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">

                    <h3>
                        Hello
                        </h3>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>This is a test</p>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="btnmodal" data-dismiss="modal" id="close">Close</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<!-- 2nd popup : EMAIL REQUEST -->


    <div class="modal custom2 fade" id="trackModal1" tabindex="-1"
        role="dialog" aria-labelledby="trackModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4>
                        Type you email
                        </h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p> Please enter your email below
                    </p>

                    <form class="contact-form row-form" name="e-mail">


                        <div class="form-field col-form x-100">
                            <input id="email" class="input-text js-input" type="email"
                                required name="email"> <label class="label" for="email">E-mail</label>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-field col-form x-100 text-center"
                            id="button_form">
                            <input class="submit-btn" type="submit" value="Submit"
                                id="button_form2" onclick=" proceed2();">
                        </div>


                    </form>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer email-popup"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS :

```
.modal.custom .modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background: #ECC1CE;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border: solid 2px white;
  margin-top: 120px;
}

.modal.custom2 .modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background: #ECC1CE;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border: solid 2px white;
  margin-top: 90px;
}
```

jQuery :

```
/* first modal */

setTimeout(function() {

        $('#trackModal').modal('show');
    }, 800);

/* second modal */

$("#stop_button").on("click", function() {

        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#trackModal1').modal('show');
            $('body').find('#trackModal1').focus();
        }, 1000);
    });
```

I assume there is a conflict between the two modals. I thought that the first one was "hiding" the second one, therefore I could not type in the second one. Therefore I tried putting the code of the e-mail modal on top of the first modal, but it did not change anything.

Do you have any idea of what is wrong here ?

Thank you.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any issue with your modals, check if you don't have input field with same id, that could cause issues. Here is your code working http://jsbin.com/xesiba/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

I have added your code to a fiddle and it seems to be working just fine
http://www.bootply.com/DrGHmstG8g

Check the rest of your javascript as the issue might be with something else that might be limiting the edit on the form.